# accessing Linked List using double pointer in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to input 10 numbers from users without using any loop/array/linked list and then i have to output max and min number among them.How it is possible?

Comment: The question and the description haven't any relation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, But a loop is used to read the user input. and please ensure your question and description have any sense.

```
    int MinVal  = 0,
        MaxVal  = 0,
        GetVal  = 0;
    cin>>GetVal;
    MaxVal=MaxVal=GetVal;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        cin>>GetVal;
        if(GetVal > MaxVal)
            MaxVal = GetVal;
        if(GetVal < MinVal)
            MinVal = GetVal;
    }
    cout<<"Max Val = "<<MaxVal<<"\n";
    cout<<"Min Val = "<<MinVal<<"\n";
```

Comment: I have made the question more elaborate. 
I want to write program that asks the user to enter 10 numbers. It should read the 10 numbers in, and the print out the biggest and the smallest numbers read. Program can use if statements but should not use loops or arrays. 
Here is some sample output: 
Enter 10 numbers: 1 10 100 20 50 77 95 145 86 32 
The smallest number was 1 and the largest number was 145

Comment: @JhonSmith you can try the above solution.